# how to find first and last name from form in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could anyone please tell me how to retrieve the value of firstname and lastname from form field.
The condition is that first name and last name is written in same text field and separated by `" "`(space). I need to get the value of it.

Here is my code and condition[image]

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/iHA8iQC1HM5OzZyIg4p3?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="first">
    <form name="myform" novalidate>
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName lastname" ng-model="user.firstname" name="username" required style="width: 300px;padding: 20px">

        <!--<span ng-show="myform.username.$dirty && myform.username.$error.required">Required</span>-->

      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" name="email" required style="width: 300px;padding: 20px;margin-top: 50px">
      </div>
      <p>{{user}}</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
var name = $scope.user.firstname.split(" ");
console.log(name[0]) // first name;
if(name.length>1)
    console.log(name[1]) // last name
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/wBBDnzSFsiIxhSXQC4q1?p=preview)

Comment: please give plunker link ..I do this on button click or add watch funtion ?

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/QkECAMaNJf2ACXo2LJpe?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('first',function($scope){
  $scope.user = {};

  $scope.nameChanged = function() {
    if ($scope.name) {
      var name = $scope.name.split(" ");

      if (name.length > 0) {
        $scope.user.firstname = name[0]; // first name;
        if(name.length>1) {
          $scope.user.lastname = name[1]; // last name
        } else {
          $scope.user.lastname = '';
        }
      }
    } else {
      $scope.user.firstname = '';
      $scope.user.lastname = '';
    }
  }
})
```

and html

```html
    <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName lastname" ng-model="name" ng-change="nameChanged()" name="username" required style="width: 300px;padding: 20px">
```

Comment: there is bug in your answer .bug is write "abc  pqr" ..it show first name and lastname ..but when user delete text ..it is also showing firstname and last name

Comment: it is showing "a" and "b" as firstname and lastname

Comment: please check still error :) ..in first name now "a" present

Comment: This guarantees the user will have a first and lastname in scope. where as the others do not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use split function to seperate the firstname and the lastname which are seperated by the space. **Note** to capture the *undefined* condition

```
        var str = "First Second";
            var res = str.split(" ");
    var first=res[0];
if(res[1]!=undefined)
    var second=res[1];
else
var second="";
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.